# How to access kubernetes guestbook application from browser?

Tags: amazon-web-services, coreos, kubernetes

I've created [Kubernetes cluster in AWS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/aws-coreos.md). 
I'm working on [guestbook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/guestbook) example based on coreos. After creating frontend service I'm able to curl localhost and access guestbook application from minion where application is built but failing to do so through browser or master.

I have tried putting diffrent publicIp in frontend service such as Public IP, Private IP assigned to instance by AWS.

Note:

1. Checked Security group in AWS and all needed ports are enabled
2. To check if minion is accessible through browser and other setting are correct, i tested nginx "Welcome to Kubernetes" application, it was successfully accessed through browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link helped : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/6158 see hack solution by kcao3.

Following are the changes :

1. add redis-master IP in slaves container /etc/hosts file
2. add redis-slave IP and redis-master IP in frontend containers in /etc/hosts file
3. checked firewall settings.

**NOTE: Its a hack so DNS settings will be the correct solution**

Answer (score 1):

Running `kubectl cluster-info` should give you a proxy endpoint on the master which you can hit to access the application. That should give an idea if there is a problem with your app in the first place.